# “Is [S] taking advantage” or “Does [S] taking advantage…”? –Which one is correct?

Tags: word-choice, questions, infinitive-vs-gerund, do-support

Which one is correct?

*Does your business partner taking advantage of you?*
or
*Is your business partner taking advantage of you?*

For me they seemed correct but I'm not familiar with the English rules for 'does' and 'is' when asking question.

Comment: The first sentence should be the following: *Does your business partner **take** advantage of you?* But, that aside, both sentences are *correct*. It's a matter of personal preference which you use.

Comment: Simple tip to understand it is 'what goes with what'. takes = does take; take = do take, and took = did take. Based on this, it is easy to make other forms. (Sorry, this is just to make one understand.) Now, takes -> She takes...She does take...Does she take?  Yes, she does (does take...), No, she doesn't...Does she not (Doesn't she...?) What does she take....?  Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

The difference between *Does ... take* and *Is ... taking* is **exactly** the same as the difference between *He takes* and *He is taking*: the difference between the "simple present" and the "continuous". (*Does ... taking* is not grammatical, as others have pointed out).

For most verbs, the "simple present" is used only in a timeless or habitual sense, and for something which is happening precisely at the moment, the "present continuous" is normal.

So *Does your business partner take advantage of you?* is a question about your partner's behaviour habitually or over a long period: the answer could be "Yes" even if right now your partner is taking good care of your interests.

*Is your business partner taking advantage of you?* is a question about what they are doing right now.

Answer (score 0):

**Which one is correct?**

1. **Does** your business partner **take** advantage of you? or
2. **Is** your business partner **taking** advantage of you?

**Note** I have edited *taking* to *take* in the first sentence.

As Jason quite correctly points out now that the sentence has been edited both are correct and It's a matter of personal preference which you use. However, **there is a difference between the sentences**. **Not in meaning but in emphasis**.

Using "**does**" (do) **adds emphasis to the question**.

> **Do shut up**, Georgia, and get on with your homework.

> **Do write** and let me know how you're getting on.

> **do**; auxiliary verb (FOR EMPHASIS); [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/do) [+ infinitive without to] **used to give extra force to the main verb**:

This is also the reason for my edit with do (does) we use "take" the infinitive form of the verb

> The infinitive form of a verb. That is, the verb in its basic form. It is the version of the verb which will appear in the dictionary. [Grammar](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/infinitive_form.htm)

Answer (score 0):

When a sentence does not have an auxiliary verb (helping verb) like `be, do, have, will, shall, would, should, can, could, may, might, must, ought`. Then, you need to use `do` to form the question.

In your case, the correct sentence will be : `Is your business partner taking advantage of you ?`.

Note : For the verb `be`, is or are as question words.